# UK visitor visa from USA - courier service link requires selection of bronze, gold, etc

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I applied online for UK short term tourist visa . I paid. Scheduled biometrics. Just finished biometrics. Now trying to purchase courier service so I can mail the documents to New York. 
But when I use the courier link, enter reference number and relevant information, it won’t let me proceed without selecting one of their priority processing options (bronze, silver, gold etc) and I’m not interested in those because they are way too expensive for me. What am I doing wrong? How can I skip that and just pay for a return shipping label to include with my documents.

So lost! Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You aren't required to use any of those services. You can [mail your application package yourself](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa#mail-your-application). In that case you must purchase your own return shipping label and include it with the package.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Michael Hampton's answer:

**29th May 2019**:
- Attended Biometric interview
- Same day, went to a UPS store and asked for a 1-day shipping label (as per the address [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa)!) and similar return shipping label to my home address. It cost ~$75 in total from Atlanta.
- Included the passport, biometric confirmation receipt and supporting documents (packet weighed about 1 lbs).
- UPS provided 2 envelopes for free since they were 1-day deliveries (the first was the "TO" envelope, the second "RETURN" envelope was folded and inserted into the first after the return address was pasted). Attaching a picture of the envelope.  [image]

**30th May 2019**: The packet arrived at the UKVI Scanning Hub address.

**18th June 2019**: I received my passport at the home address.

You can track the status of the packet [here](https://www.ups.com/track):